# "Insert into post" – Inserting form data from a pop-up window into the main window

Tags: php, javascript, forms, file-upload

I have a button labeled "Upload image", when you click the button it opens a pop-up window with a small image uploader in there. When you upload an image, I want it to say "Insert into post" in the pop-up window and when you click that it then inserts the filename of the image into the post.

I've already got a way to get the filename, all I need to know is how to SEND the data from the pop-up box form and put it into the main window.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: edit - added 'javascript' tag for better range of answers, changed 'insert' to 'file-upload'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the opener property of the pop-up window to find an hidden input in the main window:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('id_of_hidden').value = 'something';
```

Comment: But how do I use this? I've never used window.opener before

Comment: Just call it, it's a valid Javascript script. <script type="text/javascript">window.opener...

Answer (score 1):

When you open a pop-up window, the

```
window.opener
```

property will point to the parent window. You will be able to proceed from there.

[MDC documentation on window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.opener)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.opener.document.data = data_from_popup;
```